# Could mylist.count(mylist) ever return a non-zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Consider we have a list like this:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3]
```

Is it possible that `mylist.count(mylist)` return anything other that 0?

Comment: What do you think? Also, naming a variable `list` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's possible, if the `list` object contains itself:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst.append(lst)
>>> lst.count(lst)
1
>>> lst.append(lst)
>>> lst.count(lst)
2
>>> lst
[[...], [...]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) about method `list.count(x)` carefully:

> Return the number of times x appears in the list.

And now let's look at your code. You want to get *how many time* the variable `list` appears inside itself. The answer is zero in your case.

And now look at the small example of `count` usage:

```
mylist = [1,2,2,5,2,5]

print(mylist.count(2))
print(mylist.count(5))
print(mylist.count(1))
```

The output:

```
3
2
1
```

If you want to get the total count of the list elements then you should use `len`:

```
>>> len(mylist)
6
```

---

Note: `list` is the Python built-in type. You should not use it as a variable name.